# attendance date rows to column dates in mysql using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a table

info

```
idno  studno  name  
1509  001     Mark
1510  002     Dennis
1690  003     Ben
1671  004     Martial
1257  005     Lucy
```

attendance

```
idno  Date  
1509  2017/12/1
1510  2017/12/1
1671  2017/12/1
1257  2017/12/1
1509  2017/12/2
1510  2017/12/2
1671  2017/12/2
1257  2017/12/2
1690  2017/12/2
```

What I want to display is

```
name    2017/12/1  2017/12/2
Mark        P         P
Dennis      P         P
Ben         A         P
Martial     P         P
Lucy        P         P
```

Can somebody help me, and also I have seen some codes(prepared statement) but it seems no to work in phpmyadmin  routines

Comment: What have you tried if anything? You must show some effort in solving it

Comment: What you seek is called *pivoting*. It's a notorious pain in the neck in MySQL.

Comment: Yes, you're right Jones.I'm having a hard time using those codes I have seen, since I don't I understand how it works. Specially, dynamic sql.

Comment: have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table it might point you in the right direction

Comment: Just use a bit of application code to format the data. I'd show you how but I don't know vb